# ios UINavigationController in UIPopoverController and setPopoverContentSize error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I present a UINavigationController in a UIPopoverController. The UINavigationController has 2 UIViewControllers that have the same widths, but different heights. To make sure both UIViewControllers are presented in a proper sized  UIPopoverController i use the following snippet in both UIViewControllers:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.popoverControllerContainer setPopoverContentSize:self.contentSizeForViewInPopover animated:YES];
}
```

It works fine for the second UIViewController when i push it and also works fine, when i pop back to the first one, but it when i present the first one for the first time, the height of the UIViewController is smaller and it breaks the layout.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance, sincerely,

Zoli

Comment: Have you tried moving the call to `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: that will only run if i init the viewcontroller all the time. if i move it there and push a new viewcontroller from it, then when it gets popped back to, it will have the content size of the viewcontroller where it got popped from

Answer (score 0):

Try set self.contentSizeForViewInPopover in -[viewDidLoad] and set popoverController.popoverContentSize in -[viewWillAppear:]. Of course, this requires that you save a pointer to the popoverController.

Comment: that doesn't affect anything. since it can be animated it can be performed after the view is shown. And it's a nice animation, so i would like to keep it that way. i can fix it with a bool and an if in viewdidappear, it's just not elegant and i would like to know the reason why